# Adding items to existing excel file

Tags: c#, excel

I have problem. I need a program which creates a new excel file and add items to it from my application. If the file exists , I need to add next records to an existing file.

```
string Filetest = "C:\\Users\\Tom\\Documents\\File.xls";

        Excel.Application oApp;

        Excel.Workbook obook;


        oApp = new Excel.Application();
        obook = oApp.Workbooks.Add();
        oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)obook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        if (File.Exists(Filetest))
        {


        }




            oSheet.Cells[i, 1] = comboBox1.Text;
            oSheet.Cells[i, 2] = comboBox4.Text;
            oSheet.Cells[i, 3] = textBox9.Text;
            oSheet.Cells[i, 4] = textBox5.Text;
            oSheet.Cells[i, 5] = maskedTextBox6.Text;
            oSheet.Cells[i, 6] = textBox1.Text;
            oSheet.Cells[i, 7] = textBox2.Text;
            oSheet.Cells[i, 8] = maskedTextBox1.Text;
            oSheet.Cells[i, 9] = textBox21.Text;
            oSheet.Cells[i, 10] = textBox12.Text;
            oSheet.Cells[i, 11] = textBox3.Text;
            oSheet.Cells[i, 12] = textBox23.Text;
            oSheet.Cells[i, 13] = maskedTextBox6.Text;
            oSheet.Cells[i, 14] = textBox6.Text;
            oSheet.Cells[i, 15] = textBox7.Text;
            oSheet.Cells[i, 16] = "034";
            oSheet.Cells[i, 17] = comboBox3.Text;
        oSheet.Cells[i, 18] = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();

        oSheet.Cells[1000, 1] = i;



        obook.SaveAs(Filetest);
        obook.Close();
        oApp.Quit();

        i++;
```

What should i put here ?

```
if (File.Exists(Filetest))
        {


        }
```

Pls help :( and thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string Filetest = "C:\\Users\\Tom\\Documents\\File.xls";
Excel.Application oApp;
Excel.Workbook obook;

oApp = new Excel.Application();
if (File.Exists(Filetest))
{
    obook = oApp.Workbooks.Open(Filetest);
}
else
{
    obook = oApp.Workbooks.Add();
}

var oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)obook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

oSheet.Cells[i, 1] = comboBox1.Text;
// etc

obook.SaveAs(Filetest);
obook.Close();
oApp.Quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would invert your logic.  Try figuring out if you have an existing document or if you need a new one.  Something like:

```
    Excell.Application oApp ;
    if (File.Exists(Filetest))
    { 
       oApp = //lookup how to load an Excell app from a file
    }
    else{
       oApp = new Excel.Application();
       obook = oApp.Workbooks.Add();
    }

    oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)obook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

    //continue with your logic to fill in the cells and save.
```